# Сервер отвечает только на один Http запрос

Tags: java, android, httpclient

Реализовал сервер на ноуте, клиентом же является телефон с ОС Android
Делал с помощью HttpClient
Проблема в том, что сервер(ноут) отвечает только на первый запрос от клиента(телефон), а остальные будто не видит.

Сервер:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by Stanislav Trushin on 14.11.2016.
 */
public class HttpServer extends Thread {
    static Socket socket;
    static ServerSocket ss;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 3333; // случайный порт (может быть любое число от 1025 до 65535)
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port); // создаем сокет сервера и привязываем его к вышеуказанному порту
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

            socket = ss.accept(); // заставляем сервер ждать подключений и выводим сообщение когда кто-то связался с сервером
            System.out.println("Got a client :) ... Finally, someone saw me through all the cover!");
            System.out.println();

            // Берем входной и выходной потоки сокета, теперь можем получать и отсылать данные клиенту.
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            // Конвертируем потоки в другой тип, чтоб легче обрабатывать текстовые сообщения.
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            String line = null;
            while(true) {
                line = in.readUTF(); // ожидаем пока клиент пришлет строку текста.
                System.out.println("The dumb client just sent me this line : " + line);
                System.out.println("I'm sending it back...");
                out.writeUTF(line); // отсылаем клиенту обратно ту самую строку текста.
                out.flush(); // заставляем поток закончить передачу данных.
                System.out.println("Waiting for the next line...");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Клиент:

```
package com.tfirst.httpclientproject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
* Created by Stanislav Trushin on 14.11.2016.
*/
    public class HttpClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public MainActivity ma;

    public HttpClient(MainActivity ma) {
        this.ma = ma;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        int serverPort = 3333; // здесь обязательно нужно указать порт к которому привязывается сервер.
        String address = "192.168.1.33"; // это IP-адрес компьютера, где исполняется наша серверная программа.
        String line = null;
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address); // создаем объект который отображает вышеописанный IP-адрес.
            System.out.println("Any of you heard of a socket with IP address " + address + " and port " + serverPort + "?");
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort); // создаем сокет используя IP-адрес и порт сервера.
            System.out.println("Yes! I just got hold of the program.");

            // Берем входной и выходной потоки сокета, теперь можем получать и отсылать данные клиентом.
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            // Конвертируем потоки в другой тип, чтоб легче обрабатывать текстовые сообщения.
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            // Создаем поток для чтения с клавиатуры.
            System.out.println("Type in something and press enter. Will send it to the server and tell ya what it thinks.");
            System.out.println();

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Sending this line to the server...");
                out.writeUTF(Arrays.toString(strings)); // отсылаем введенную строку текста серверу.
                out.flush(); // заставляем поток закончить передачу данных.
                line = in.readUTF(); // ждем пока сервер отошлет строку текста.
                System.out.println(line);
                return line;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return line;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String line) {
        ma.setTextToTextView(line);
    }
}
```

Проблема думаю на стороне сервера, но не могу понять, в чем все-таки.